# Programmatically creating SAML apps

Tags: api, saml, onelogin

Can this be done? Or what would the correct approach be?

As part of our provisioning step for new instances (custom domain, resources, etc.) of our software we would like to automate the setup of the IdP. As it is, we set this up manually.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do that today.

Having said that, it's planned to be implemented later this year.

[Edit]

### This is no longer true

Just to return to this, the API was released a while ago.

Check out -
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/apps/overview

I'd start with the **SAML test connector (Advanced)** as a starting point and use the API to change the various SAML settings.

Comment: I just came to SO to ask same when designing our new app for internal management. It is June 2020 and I was not able to find any clues on how to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer - The Application API was released a while ago and should allow you to programmatically create/update a SAML connector (at least on thew OneLogin side of things)